# All VB script file extensions

Tags: vbscript

What are all the file extensions used to execute a visual basic script file, for example .vbs, and .vbe and so on? I believe there are more, but there's no way I can find them!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia of all places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) will tell you that the available file extensions for `VBScript` and file types which can contain `VBScript` are as follows:

> Filename extensions   .vbs, .vbe, .wsf, .wsc (.hta, .htm, .html, .asp)

I don't know if this is a truly exhaustive list though.